# Cloudflare API with PHP problems

Tags: php, cloudflare

I need to sent parameters for the function

`Cloudflare\API\Endpoints\AccessRules::createRule()`

```
public function createRule(
    string $zoneID,
    string $mode,
    Configurations $configuration,
    string $notes = null
): bool {
    $options = [
        'mode' => $mode,
        'configuration' => $configuration->getArray()
    ];

    if ($notes !== null) {
        $options['notes'] = $notes;
    }

    $query = $this->adapter->post('zones/' . $zoneID . '/firewall/access_rules/rules', $options);

    $this->body = json_decode($query->getBody());

    if (isset($this->body->result->id)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My code:

```
$key     = new Cloudflare\API\Auth\APIKey($userEmail, $api_key);
$adapter = new Cloudflare\API\Adapter\Guzzle($key);
$fw      = new Cloudflare\API\Endpoints\AccessRules($adapter);

$configData= [
    'target' => 'ip',
    'value' => '1.2.3.4',
];

$result=$fw->createRule($zoneID,'block',$configData,"Auto block");
```

And my error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to         Cloudflare\API\Endpoints\AccessRules::createRule() must be an instance of Cloudflare\API\Configurations\Configurations, array given
```

I do `$configData` as a object - the same.
Could you tell me - how I should create instance in `$configData`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this this way:

```
$configData = new Cloudflare\API\Configurations\AccessRules();
$configData->setIP('1.2.3.4');
```